# What would cause the responsive features on this site not work on mobile?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, responsive-design

I am using a Bootstrap Template, that you can see the live version here - https://02dc74ce3e31e56a52ebcc845dca58e87283aabe.googledrive.com/host/0Bxbofwq0kd4ReUt2YWVOYmt3WVU/

If you view it on a mobile device, you will see how the responsiveness of Bootstrap kicks in.

But when I applied it to [my Rails app](http://ognr.herokuapp.com/), the mobile version does not look the same.

Any ideas what may be causing the discrepancy?

You can see the differences especially in both the main 'content' area with the story (notice on my version you see multiple stories in the main view, but on the original you only see 1 story and you can read the content more easily). You can also see it when you press the buttons.

Press the 'blue' button to the right top of the original and you will notice that the sidepanel comes out at the top like it should. But on my version it still comes to the side and everything is small.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: am i missing something ?`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> ?`

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: i dont see a viewport tag in the rails app

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer Interesting. Could that really be it? Hrmmm...

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer Dude....you were SOOO on the money with that one. Awesome suggestion. If you leave this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `application.html.erb`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made too many changes while you are implementing the html in your rails view. 
Like original header have following content :

```
<header class="header">
  <hgroup class="pull-left">
    <h1 class="site-title">
      <a href="index.html" title="Von" rel="home">
        <i class="fa fa-lemon-o"></i> Von
      </a>
    </h1>
  </hgroup>
  <div class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="togglesidebar">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
</header>
```

But in your view instead of `<hgroup class="pull-left">` you have `<hgroup class="pull-left col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">` and for `<div class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="togglesidebar">` you have `<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 masthead-group-3">` also You added two more element in between these two element that destroyed your all header view.

You haven't used middle section from html design it seems you write your own. In your `<header class="entry-header">` You created div instead of image tag. So every thing started distorted here. You include header footer section for each main section. But it's not big issue. Try remove div for `confirmed` and `unconfirmed` and use image instead. SO you will have proper view. Also remove row class from view that you added so view look more symmetric.

In your about section. When you try to see on mobile view.  width of main container `<div style="display: inline-block;" class="col-sm-3 sidebar" id="secondary">` is calculated on the basis of it's child element like `<div class="about">`. As your child element is form and it's having width less than the width displayed on form so remaining section not having proper background color `#1c171e`. So try increase width of you form control or `<h4>Submit Report</h4>` like `<h4>Submit Report &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>` (kind of hack)under about section You will get proper view for this also.

Comment: Ok I made some changes. I reverted much of the post structure to be identical to the theme. Can you checkout my app link again and see. It is still giving me the issue, even though it does look a bit better. N

Comment: You haven't made any changes in header part as suggested. login and filter breaking your theme. Also submit news width is too much. Also you didn't changed your news section width so it's also breaking in modbile view.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, and for your effort, but the real answer was the `meta viewport` tag as @SaiRamSudheer pointed out in his comment. That one line changed everything. I will certainly play around with your changes for some other issues I was having, but that one `meta` tag solved the core issue I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your css file, you have loaded similar css multiple times. Consider the fact that, if everything else suggested by the people above has been corrected, the placement of the css files in the application scss file could overwrite your correct code.

I would also check the viewport meta tag as suggested above

Answer (score 1):

If you try calling the CSS and JS being used as individual standalone files, instead of minified, do you still have this issue? Order of these files will matter too. I've seen lots of quirky issues when one JS gets loaded before another, same goes for CSS.

P.S. I would leave this information as a 'Comment' vs. Answer but I don't have enough stack overflow credit yet to do so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you have using `rails g scaffold` that you remove the `scaffold.css` file.

Comment: Never used `scaffold` so that's not the issue.

Comment: Make sure that some of your other CSS isn't causing the issue. Try to remove one file at a time to see if that helps.